# Heroku push -f rejected

Tags: git, heroku

I am a newbie for Git and having an issue with push application code to Heroku using `-f` flag(this is a testing app)
It has been working well for more than 1 yr.

Here is my situation:

I had 2 feature-branches (let's say a and b)

This is what I've done:

`git checkout master` -> `git merge a` -> `git checkout b` -> `git rebase -i master`(no conflicts) -> `git push -f heroku b:master`.

Tried to upload files to new app on Heroku, but it gave me the same error. I couldn't identify the issue from the logs from Heroku.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

**Error:**

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  8.9.4
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 8.9.4...
   Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
   Using default npm version: 5.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
   Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
-----> Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json)

   > itask@0.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf
   > npm i -g pm2 && pm2 install pm2-logrotate

   /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/pm2 -> /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
   /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/pm2-dev -> /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
   /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/pm2-docker -> /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
   /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/pm2-runtime -> /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
   + pm2@2.10.1
   added 243 packages in 9.395s

   -------------

   __/\\\\\\____/\\____________/\\____/\\\\_____
   _/\/////////\_/\\\________/\\\__/\///////\___
   _/\_______/\_/\//\____/\//\_///______//\__
   _/\\\\\\/__/\\///\/\/_/\___________/\/___
   _/\/////////____/\__///\/___/\________/\//_____
   _/\_____________/\____///_____/\_____/\//________
   _/\_____________/\_____________/\___/\/___________
   _/\_____________/\_____________/\__/\\\\\\\_
   _///______________///______________///__///////////////__


   Community Edition

   Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
   with a built-in Load Balancer.


   Start and Daemonize any application:
   $ pm2 start app.js

   Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
   $ pm2 start api.js -i 4

   Monitor in production:
   $ pm2 monitor

   Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
   $ pm2 startup

   To go further checkout:
   http://pm2.io/


   -------------

   [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/app/.pm2
   [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
   [PM2][Module] Installing module pm2-logrotate
   [PM2][Module] Calling [NPM] to install pm2-logrotate ...
   + pm2-logrotate@2.4.0
   added 252 packages in 9.016s
   [PM2][Module] Module downloaded
   [PM2][WARN] Applications pm2-logrotate not running, starting...
   [PM2] App [pm2-logrotate] launched (1 instances)
   [PM2][Module] Monitoring module behavior for potential issue (5secs...)
   == pm2-logrotate ==
   ┌────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
   │ key            │ value               │
   ├────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
   │ max_size       │ 10M                 │
   │ retain         │ all                 │
   │ compress       │ false               │
   │ dateFormat     │ YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss │
   │ workerInterval │ 30                  │
   │ rotateInterval │ 0 0 * * *           │
   │ rotateModule   │ true                │
   └────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
   [PM2][Module] Module successfully installed and launched
   [PM2][Module] Edit configuration via: `pm2 conf`
   ┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬──────────┐
   │ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem │ user │ watching │
   └──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴──────────┘
   Module activated
   ┌───────────────┬─────────┬────────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────┬─────────────┬────────┐
   │ Module        │ version │ target PID │ status │ restart │ cpu │ memory      │ user   │
   ├───────────────┼─────────┼────────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────┼─────────────┼────────┤
   │ pm2-logrotate │ N/A     │ N/A        │ online │ 0       │ 7%  │ 25.547 MB   │ u49679 │
   └───────────────┴─────────┴────────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────┴─────────────┴────────┘
   Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app

   > v8-profiler@5.2.12 preinstall /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-profiler
   >


   > v8-debug@0.4.6 preinstall /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug
   >


   > v8-debug@0.4.6 install /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug
   > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@0.4.6 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
   make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build'
   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/debug/src/debug.o
   In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:82:0,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   ../../nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> NanIntern::To(v8::Handle<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Int32; v8::Handle<v8::Integer> = v8::Local<v8::Integer>]’:
   ../../nan/nan_new.h:34:64: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Int32> v8::Value::ToInt32() const’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:9743): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   To<v8::Int32>(v8::Handle<v8::Integer> i)   { return i->ToInt32(); }
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> NanIntern::To(v8::Handle<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Uint32; v8::Handle<v8::Integer> = v8::Local<v8::Integer>]’:
   ../../nan/nan_new.h:39:65: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Uint32> v8::Value::ToUint32() const’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:9737): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   To<v8::Uint32>(v8::Handle<v8::Integer> i)  { return i->ToUint32(); }
   ^
   In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
   from ../../nan/nan.h:82,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::BooleanObject>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::BooleanObject>::New(bool)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:49:38: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::BooleanObject::New(bool)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:4793): Pass an isolate [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::BooleanObject::New(value).As<v8::BooleanObject>();
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::Script>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::Script>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:166:69: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1422): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &src);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::Script>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::Script>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::ScriptOrigin&)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:173:69: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1422): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &src);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::String>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::String>::New(const uint8_t*, int)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:206:42: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate*, const uint8_t*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:2668): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::String::kNormalString, length);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::String>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::String>::New(v8::String::ExternalStringResource*)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:217:66: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewExternal(v8::Isolate*, v8::String::ExternalStringResource*)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:2707): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::String::NewExternal(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), value);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::UnboundScript>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:237:76: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1403): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &src);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::UnboundScript>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::ScriptOrigin&)’:
   ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:244:76: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1403): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &src);
   ^
   In file included from ../src/debug.cc:2:0:
   ../../nan/nan.h: At global scope:
   ../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
   NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
   NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘bool NanIdleNotification(int)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:289:71: warning: ‘bool v8::Isolate::IdleNotification(int)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:7428): use IdleNotificationDeadline() [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->IdleNotification(idle_time_in_ms);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: At global scope:
   ../../nan/nan.h:473:20: error: variable or field ‘NanAddGCEpilogueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:473:7: error: ‘GCEpilogueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:474:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘gc_type_filter’
   , v8::GCType gc_type_filter = v8::kGCTypeAll) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:479:20: error: variable or field ‘NanRemoveGCEpilogueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:479:7: error: ‘GCEpilogueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCEpilogueCallback callback) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:484:20: error: variable or field ‘NanAddGCPrologueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:484:7: error: ‘GCPrologueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:485:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘gc_type_filter’
   , v8::GCType gc_type_filter = v8::kGCTypeAll) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:490:20: error: variable or field ‘NanRemoveGCPrologueCallback’ declared void
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:490:7: error: ‘GCPrologueCallback’ is not a member of ‘v8::Isolate’
   v8::Isolate::GCPrologueCallback callback) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:569:11: error: ‘WeakCallbackData’ in namespace ‘v8’ does not name a type
   const v8::WeakCallbackData<T, _NanWeakCallbackInfo<T, P> > &data) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:569:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   const v8::WeakCallbackData<T, _NanWeakCallbackInfo<T, P> > &data) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:569:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   const v8::WeakCallbackData<T, _NanWeakCallbackInfo<T, P> > &data) {
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘void _NanWeakCallbackDispatcher(int)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:570:42: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
   _NanWeakCallbackInfo<T, P> *info = data.GetParameter();
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: At global scope:
   ../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
   , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
   , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
   v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
   v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:672:67: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
   ^
   In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:25:0,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/node_buffer.h:67:40: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t)’ [-fpermissive]
   NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
   ^
   In file included from ../src/debug.cc:2:0:
   ../../nan/nan.h:672:67: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((char*)data), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
   return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
   return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
   return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Script> NanCompileScript(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::ScriptOrigin&)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:710:74: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1422): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &source);
   ^
   ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Script> NanCompileScript(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
   ../../nan/nan.h:717:74: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1422): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), &source);
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::Call(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:18:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Debug::Call(v8::Handle<v8::Function>&)’
   v8::Debug::Call(fn);
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:18:27: note: candidate is:
   In file included from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
   from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/node.h:63,
   from ../../nan/nan.h:24,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:193:42: note: static v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Debug::Call(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
   static MaybeLocal<Value> Call(
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:193:42: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
   static MaybeLocal<Value> Call(
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::SendCommand(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:28:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Debug::GetDebugContext()’
   v8::Isolate* debug_isolate = v8::Debug::GetDebugContext()->GetIsolate();
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:28:65: note: candidate is:
   In file included from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
   from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/node.h:63,
   from ../../nan/nan.h:24,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:209:39: note: static v8::Local<v8::Context> v8::Debug::GetDebugContext(v8::Isolate*)
   static Local<Context> GetDebugContext(Isolate* isolate));
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:209:39: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
   static Local<Context> GetDebugContext(Isolate* isolate));
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:30:73: warning: ‘static void v8::Debug::SendCommand(v8::Isolate*, const uint16_t*, int, v8::Debug::ClientData*)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:169): No longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::Debug::SendCommand(debug_isolate, *command, command.length());
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::RunScript(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:43:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Debug::GetDebugContext()’
   v8::Context::Scope context_scope(v8::Debug::GetDebugContext());
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:43:69: note: candidate is:
   In file included from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
   from /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/node.h:63,
   from ../../nan/nan.h:24,
   from ../src/debug.cc:2:
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:209:39: note: static v8::Local<v8::Context> v8::Debug::GetDebugContext(v8::Isolate*)
   static Local<Context> GetDebugContext(Isolate* isolate));
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8-debug.h:209:39: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
   static Local<Context> GetDebugContext(Isolate* isolate));
   ^
   /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle<v8::Object> nodex::Debug::createExceptionDetails(v8::Handle<v8::Message>)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:76:101: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Array> v8::StackTrace::AsArray()’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:1645): Use native API instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   exceptionDetails->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("stackTrace"), message->GetStackTrace()->AsArray());
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::EvaluateWithExceptionDetails(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:93:22: warning: ‘v8::TryCatch::TryCatch()’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:8260): Use isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::TryCatch tryCatch;
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::SetNonEnumProperty(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:119:56: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:3099): Use CreateDataProperty / DefineOwnProperty [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   object->ForceSet(args[1], args[2], v8::DontEnum);
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::InternalConstructorName(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:194:23: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   result_type = "";
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:201:26: warning: ‘v8::TryCatch::TryCatch()’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:8260): Use isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::TryCatch tryCatch;
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc:202:94: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::String>)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:3388): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::Local<v8::Value> constructor = object->GetRealNamedProperty(constructorSymbol);
   ^
   ../src/debug.cc: In static member function ‘static void nodex::Debug::Eval(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
   ../src/debug.cc:293:22: warning: ‘v8::TryCatch::TryCatch()’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:8260): Use isolate version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   v8::TryCatch tryCatch;
   ^
   make: *** [Release/obj.target/debug/src/debug.o] Error 1
   make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build'
   gyp ERR! build error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1012-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64/debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug
   gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
   gyp ERR! not ok
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64' (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1012-aws
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
   Failed to execute '/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/tmp/build_8e25140fb34c2938891ccf3f4223dbdf/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v57-linux-x64' (1)
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.SyDfA/_logs/2018-03-07T00_29_34_599Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/

   Love,
   Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding node/npm version explicitly on package.json resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you go through your `package.json` and verify, it looks like you either have some dependencies not included or your build environment not specified.